# Set path to Eclipse

Tags: 16.04, eclipse, environment-variables

My Eclipse installer has installed Eclipse in `~/eclipse/cpp-oxygen/eclipse`. But I don't have its icon in the Unity menu and command prompt doesn't see the eclipse binary.

I have set `PATH` in  `.profile` (not sure this is right place)

```
PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:~/eclipse/cpp-oxygen/eclipse"
```

Now I get an error when I run Eclipse:

```
The Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its 
home directory.
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `"…:~/eclipse/cpp-oxygen/eclipse"` doesn't work the way you appear to intend. `~` isn't expanded inside quotation marks or after `:`. You need to replace it with `$HOME`. I don't know if that's going to solve the Eclipse start-up issue though.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the icon problem by following below steps.

Step 1. Open Terminal and run command

```
vim ~/.local/share/applications/eclipse.desktop
```

Step 2. Copy and paste the content below into the file and save

```
Name=Eclipse JEE Oxygen
Type=Application
Exec=/home/tungbui/eclipse/java-oxygen/eclipse/eclipse
Terminal=false
Icon=/home/tungbui/eclipse/java-oxygen/eclipse/icon.xpm
Comment=Integrated Development Environment
NoDisplay=false
Categories=Development;IDE;
Name[en]=Eclipse
```

Remember to replace the Exec and Icon location. 
Hope it helps.

Reference: https://websiteforstudents.com/how-to-install-eclipse-oxygen-ide-on-ubuntu-167-04-17-10-18-04/